# Core Data performance - massive memory usage while fetching and saving objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory-leaks, nstableview

I'm making a app for OS X and i face a big problem with memory which i tried to solve since couple of days without success. The app is a pasteboard manager which log all of items and show them in a NSTableView. The Controller of the TableView implement two protocol NSTableViewDataSource and NSTableViewDelegate to displaying TableCells. I don't use NSArrayController and Interface bindings.

So far so good, the app worked well with under 15 MB of memory. But now i want to persist all of the items with Core Data so that the items could be loaded when users are going to start the app. It works also but with very big memory foot print of over 200 MB. And i know that it is just too much for such a app.

I just created the app with core data app template of XCode 6 beta on OS X Yosemite beta. I tried to use Xcode instruments to find the bugs but as newbie this helps me not so much. I've read docs about Core Data Performance and tried to set the Undo Manager of ManagedObjectContext to nil but this bring nothings.

The followed snippet code show how i store and load the records with Core Data. I hope some help or advice to reduce the memory usage of my app.

```c
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _savedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        /* Core Data - load items */
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PasteboardItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:entityDesc];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *storedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        [_savedItems addObjectsFromArray:storedObjects];
        /* Core Data End */

        _pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        changesCount = (int)[_pasteBoard changeCount];
        [self startFetchPasteBoardItemsTimer];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)fetchNewPasteboardItem {
    PasteboardItem *newPbItem = [self buildPbItemFromPasteBoard:_pasteBoard];
    if ([_savedItems containsObject:newPbItem]) {
        return;
    }

    NSRunningApplication *sourceApp = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication];
    NSImage *sourceImage = [sourceApp icon];

    [newPbItem setSourceAppImage:sourceImage];


    /* Core Data - Persist new item */

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *newPasteboardItem;
    newPasteboardItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PasteboardItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.stringValue forKeyPath:@"stringValue"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.rtfData forKeyPath:@"rtfData"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.pdfData forKeyPath:@"pdfData"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.filenames forKeyPath:@"filenames"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.url forKeyPath:@"url"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.contentImage forKeyPath:@"contentImage"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.imageInfo forKeyPath:@"imageInfo"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.sourceAppImage forKeyPath:@"sourceAppImage"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.createdDate forKeyPath:@"createdDate"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.lastUsedDate forKeyPath:@"lastUsedDate"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.overview forKeyPath:@"overview"];
    [newPasteboardItem setValue:newPbItem.mainText forKeyPath:@"mainText"];

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];

    /* Core Data - End of Persistence */

    [_savedItems insertObject:newPbItem atIndex:0];
    [self updateLastItemTimestamp];
}
```

Two screenshot of memory increasing with instruments.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFsMG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aES9I.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an [NSXMLStoreType persistent store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html), which is a type of atomic store. This means that when the store is instantiated and added to the persistent store coordinator the *entire* object graph is loaded into memory. This is why your application is using this much memory - every object in the store is in memory, all the time. In contrast an incremental store like the `NSSQLiteStoreType` will only keep in memory the objects that are in use, which can be much more efficient.